# add column Numpy array python

Tags: python, numpy

I am very new to python and am very familiar with R, but my question is very simple using Numpy Arrays:

Observe:

I have one array X of dimension (100,2) of floating point type and I want to add a 3rd column, preferably into a new Numpy array of dimension (100,3) such that the 3rd column = col(1)^2 for every row in array of X.

My understanding is Numpy arrays are generally of fixed dimension so I'm OK with creating a new array of dim 100x3, I just don't know how to do so using Numpy arrays.

Thanks!

Comment: `np.zeroes((100,3)` makes a float array (default dtype) with the desired shape.  Keep `np.zeros` and `np.ones` under your pillow for future use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by ***creating a new array and then concatenating it***. For instance, say that `M` is currently your array.

You can compute col(1)^2 as `C = M[:,0] ** 2` (which I'm interpreting as column 1 squared, not column 1 to the power of the values in column two). `C` will now be an array with shape (100, ), so we can reshape it using `C = np.expand_dims(C, 1)` which will create a new axis of length 1, so our new column now has shape (100, 1). This is important because we want all both of our arrays to have the same number of dimensions when concatenating them.

The last step here is to concatenate them using `np.concatenate`. In total, our result looks like this

```
C = M[:, 0] ** 2
C = np.expand_dims(C, 1)
M = np.concatenate([M, C], axis=1) #third row will now be col(1) ^ 2
```

If you're the kind of person who likes to do things in one line, you have:

```
M = np.concatenate([M, np.expand_dims(M[:, 0] ** 2, 0)], axis=1)
```

That being said, I would recommend looking at *Pandas*, it supports these actions more naturally, in my opinion. In Pandas, it would be

```
M["your_col_3_name"] = M["your_col_1_name"] ** 2
```

where M is a pandas dataframe.

Comment: As you can see, even though ndarrays are of fixed dimension (just as tuples and strings are of fixed dim AND value) they can just be overwritten, and the old array will be garbage collected eventually

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  Is there anyway to type cast an numpy array into a panda array, since the above Pandas array works much more similarly to R.

Also if I wanted to row append Numpy arrays of the same column space would concatenate work ie if A = (100,3), B = (50,3) would np.concatenate(A,B,axis=1) give me an array of dimension (150,3)?

Comment: `np.concatenate((A, B), axis=0)` would do the job, `axis=1` would fail because all input arrays need the same shape in the other axes... notice you are missing parenthesis around `A, B`

Answer (score 0):

```py
# generate an array with shape (100,2), fill with 2.
a = np.full((100,2),2)

# calcuate the square to first column, this will be a 1-d array.
squared=a[:,0]**2

# concatenate the 1-d array to a, 
# first need to convert it to 2-d arry with shape (100,1) by reshape(-1,1)
c = np.concatenate((a,squared.reshape(-1,1)),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Append with axis=1 should work.

```python
a = np.zeros((5,2))
b = np.ones((5,1))
print(np.append(a,b,axis=1))
```

This should return:

```python
[[0,0,1],  
 [0,0,1],  
 [0,0,1],  
 [0,0,1],  
 [0,0,1]]
```